# What are the prerequisites for Facebook stream.publish?

Tags: php, api, facebook

I'm wondering if someone would help me troubleshoot my test for stream.publish. I thought I had all the right pieces. Here's the code:

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';
$appapikey = 'xxxxxxx';
$appsecret = 'xxxxxxx';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();


$message = "Will this status show up and allow me to dominate the world?!";
$uid = $user_id;
echo $uid;
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message,$uid);
```

What I'm expecting is my status to change to $message's content. What happens instead is that my UID is echo'd, and then it throws a 500 error. I've allowed `publish_stream` as well as  `offline_access` (verified in my app settings, via my profile), the the API key hooks this small bit of code to my app. What other pieces do I need to make this simple example work? I'm finding the FB documentation a little hard to put together.

-- The include is the official PHP Facebook library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stream_publish() takes more than two arguments:

```
stream_publish($message, $attachment = null, 
               $action_links = null, $target_id = null, 
               $uid = null)
```

Where $target_id is the user or page you're publishing **to** and $uid is the user or page who is doing the publishing - and which defaults to your session id. To be completely explicit about this, I think you need to try

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';
$appapikey = 'xxxxxxx';
$appsecret = 'xxxxxxx';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();

$message = "Will this status show up and allow me to dominate the world?!";

echo $user_id;
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message,null,null,$user_id,$user_id);
```

An alternate form might be:

```
$app_id = 'xxxxxxx'; 
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message,null,null,$user_id,$app_id);
```

Comment: My issue was that all the parameters were listed as optional, so I only included what I thought I needed, without thinking that the order of them dictated what they meant (IE, to use placeholders to answer ALL the available parameters) Thanks a lot for helping me with this.

Answer (score 2):

This one works in 2011! I had the same problem. Most of the tuts seem to be out of date thanks to Facebook changes. I eventually found a way that worked and did a quick blog article about it here:

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=214

There's also a screen shot to show you what the result is. Make sure you also see the blog post about authentication though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$uid` variable as it is not needed for publishing. Refer to this [wiki entry](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish) for more info

```
$stream_post_id = $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message); 
//returns $post_id to use if you want to revert the creation.
```

Comment: In my script then how will it know to which user's account to publish the message?

Comment: call like this 

$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $attachment, $actionlinks);

and it will publish to all your friends wall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use streamPublish with an iFrame application, here is an awesome step-by-step tutorial that doesn't have to use getAppPermissions:

http://thetechnicalexperience.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-fbconnectstreampublish.html